# SpringBoot cron expression to run at 7.30 am from 25th March to 10th April every year

Tags: spring-boot, cron

Can someone please help in creating a 6 digit SpringBoot cron expression to run at 7.30 am every day from 25th March to 10th April every year.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can make a singular cron to start midway through 1 month and end in another. You can however get this using 2 cron's
`30 7 25-31 3 *` and `30 7 1-10 4 *`.

Update a mock on how I think you should be able to use both cron's for same job (untested).
It might be necesary to create 2 `JobDetailFactoryBean` (and in the worst case 2 job classes) but I think you should be able to use 2 `CronTriggerFactoryBean` if they don't overlap

```java
@Bean
public CronTriggerFactoryBean trigger1(JobDetail job1,
    @Value("${cron1property}") String cron)
{
    CronTriggerFactoryBean factoryBean = new CronTriggerFactoryBean();
    factoryBean.setJobDetail(updateOpenproviderDataJob);
    factoryBean.setCronExpression(cron);
    return factoryBean;
}

@Bean
public CronTriggerFactoryBean trigger2(JobDetail job1,
    @Value("${cron2property}") String cron)
{
    CronTriggerFactoryBean factoryBean = new CronTriggerFactoryBean();
    factoryBean.setJobDetail(updateOpenproviderDataJob);
    factoryBean.setCronExpression(cron);
    return factoryBean;
}

@Bean
public JobDetailFactoryBean job1()
{
    JobDetailFactoryBean factoryBean = new JobDetailFactoryBean();
    factoryBean.setJobClass(jobClass);
    factoryBean.setDurability(true);
    factoryBean.setDescription(YourJob.class.getSimpleName());
    return factoryBean;
}
```

Comment: And any idea how to integrate these two crons for a single scheduler method?

Comment: @NehaKarur Updated answer with a mock for bean definition for the jobs, asuming you already have a class implementing the `Job` interface and are using quartz. Beans should go into a config file. Code is not tested so might need some tweaking.